# Unable to switch between segments for UISegment Control

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

Below is the code snippet I am using to set up my UISegment Control

```
//Add UIView below the nav bar
UIView *buttonContainer = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];

[self.view addSubview:buttonContainer];

//Set up segment control
NSString *nicknameLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.nickname];

UISegmentedControl *tempSegmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nicknameLabel,@"Friends", @"Everyone", nil]];
tempSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(-8, 44, 336, 30);

self.segmentControl = tempSegmentControl;
[self.segmentControl setWidth:112 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[self.segmentControl setWidth:112 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
[self.segmentControl setWidth:112 forSegmentAtIndex:2];
self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
[self.segmentControl addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleControls:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.segmentControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStylePlain];

[self changeSegmentFontSize];

[tempSegmentControl release];
[buttonContainer addSubview:self.segmentControl];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:buttonContainer];
[buttonContainer bringSubviewToFront:self.segmentControl];
[buttonContainer release];
```

However, I in the app, I am unable to switch between the segments for the segmented control. (only show default first segment highlighted)

[image]

Any advice on how I can fix this?

Comment: Make sure your container is large enough to hold the segmented control.  i.e.  If you turn clipping on for the container, is the segmented control clipped?  The clipped regions (even with clipping turned off so that they are visible) will NOT receive touch events - unless you implement special code for the `hitTest:withEvent:` method of the container that says otherwise....  ALSO - make sure your `segmentControl` is enabled.

Comment: Why are you adding another uiview subview? You can directly add the uisegmented control as a subview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a bounds problem. The containing view has bounds {0, 0, 320, 30} while the segmented control has {-8, 44, 336, 30}. This means the segmented control is technically "outside" its containing view and the iOS hit test will not register a touch.

Try not setting the segmented control's frame (temporarily comment out the `tempSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(-8, 44, 336, 30);` line) and see what happens.

Comment: Yup. Thanks! I changed the bounds and now it works. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

1. Check that userInteractionEnabled is set to TRUE for your view, buttonContainer, and segment control.
2. Check that the bounds of the buttonContainer's superview are wide and tall enough to fully contain the buttonContainer.  If they're not then hit-testing wont work and the segmented control wont get any touches.